# Will transformer work with lower voltage?

Tags: ac-dc

I'm looking for a way to convert 8VAC to direct current. I found a converter that can convert 10V~20V to 12V3A.

Will the converter work when I input it with 8V?
And how much output voltage will be generated?

It the Szduli S3-A121203. 36W AC-DC Converter.

Comment: A converter is not a transformer. Your title and body of text are in conflict here. Which is it?

Comment: please add part numbers, or better yet check the datasheets for the relevant figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it's likely a simple buck converter/regulator. The minimum input voltage is stated as 10VAC. That low a voltage may or may not allow full output current, depending on how the manufacturer chose to specify their product (personally, unless specifically stated otherwise on a reliable datasheet, I would not count on being able to get much output current at the absolute minimum input voltage, and certainly not over temperature- there is very little margin at 10VAC in).

If I am correct, then it will certainly not regulate with 8V in, which would yield insufficient voltage on the internal DC rail. So you'd likely get 8 or 10V out with a lot of mains ripple.

You may need a buck-boost converter if you need 12V out and there is much tolerance on the 8VAC input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert Alternating Current of 8V RMS to Direct Current, you dont need Transformer, you need a rectifier of your wish, say Full Bridge Rectifier or Single Diode Rectifier. If you want the 8V to be higher like 12V you need transformer of appropriate turn ratio and then you need to pass it to a rectifier and get Direct current .

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq5gYL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f80dty.png)</sup>